# Number of processors assigned to Guest OSs (time slicing?)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

- VMWare Workstation Pro 14
- Windows 10 v1809
- 4 processor CPU (Core i7-6700 3.4GHz)

I am wondering about how to assign processors to my Guest OSs.

I am using guest OSs

- CentOS 6.9
- CentOS 6.9
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Windows 7
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10

If I assign each processors to fours guest OSs, that are equal to the physical number of processors (four), and also use processors for host OS. But I have no problem in doing so.

Question: Are the processors assigned using time-slicing, making a single CPU assigned to two Guest OS in turn?

If so, I am thinking to increase number of processors assigned to some GuestOS (e.g. 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a CPU scheduler that's in use. Basically, it makes it so that the VM can make use of any available CPU instead of being pinned to a specific CPU where it could get stuck waiting for an extended period of time.

More information about the scheduler concept can be found in the following whitepaper: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vmware-vsphere-cpu-sched-performance-white-paper.pdf

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I was searching such kind of documents for VMWare.

Comment: I use multiple guest OSs, but those OSs are not used with high CPU usage for numerical simulations. Considering your information, I can make sense.